# Error with passing a pointer using threads

Tags: c++, unix, g++, pthreads

Updated code: 3/7/11 : 9:29pm

```
using namespace std;

void * matrixACreate(void * param);  
void *status;

struct a  
{  
     int Arow; // Matrix A    
     int Acol; // WxX  
     int low;  // Range low  
     int high;  
 };  

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{     
    struct a matrix_mult_info;  

    matrix_mult_info.Arow = atoi(argv[1]); // Matrix A  
    matrix_mult_info.Acol = atoi(argv[2]); // WxX

    matrix_mult_info.low = atoi(argv[5]); // Range low
    matrix_mult_info.high = atoi(argv[6]);

    pthread_t matrixAthread;

    pthread_t runner;  
    int error, retValue;  

    struct a * a = (struct a *) malloc(sizeof(struct a));   
    error = pthread_create(&matrixAthread, NULL, matrixACreate, a );  
    //error = pthread_create(&matrixAthread, NULL, matrixBCreate, sendB);  
    retValue = pthread_join(matrixAthread, &status);  
    //retValue = pthread_join(matrixBthread, &status);  

    return 0;  
}

void * matrixACreate(void * param) {    
    struct a * matrix = (struct a *) param;    
    int range = ((matrix->high - matrix->low) + 1);    
    cout << matrix->Arow << endl;    
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Please make *some* effort to format your code for future questions. It will help you understand the problem, and **help us help you**.

Comment: Likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226033/multiplying-matrices-error-expected-primary-expression-before-struct and also multiple user accounts

Comment: Seriously, **turn off your caps lock key** when posting comments.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct a * a = (struct a *) malloc(sizeof(struct a)); 
// init a's members
error = pthread_create(&matrixAthread, NULL, matrixACreate, a);
```

EDIT: In response to updated question:

```
void * matrixACreate(void * param) {  
    struct a * matrix = (struct a *) param;  
    int range = ((matrix->high - matrix->low) + 1);  
    cout << matrix->Arow << endl;  
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Show us complete code, and define what "does not work" means. Crash? Compiler error?

Comment: If it doesn't work, you're either not telling us something or you're not following Erik's example.

Comment: Where would I put the struct a * and the NULL?

Comment: I followed your suggestions and got:
main.cpp:10: error: expected initializer before 'void'
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:42: error: 'matrixACreate' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:44: error: 'status' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function 'void* matrixACreate(void*)':
main.cpp:63: error: redefinition of 'void* matrixACreate(void*)'
main.cpp:49: error: 'void* matrixACreate(void*)' previously defined here

Comment: Update the matrixACreate prototype as well. `void * matrixACreate(void * param);`

Comment: OK IT RUNS, BUT   cout << matrix->Arow << endl;   IS PRINTING 1  I AM INPUTTING : A.OUT 4 5 5 7 -5 10

Comment: @ohlegend: Why do you feel the need to shout?