# Using a thread, what do I pass into my function

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, g++, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with passing a pointer using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227087/error-with-passing-a-pointer-using-threads)

I am trying to figure out what I pass into the function.

I have no idea what to do, I have never used threads before.
The problem area is marked.

```
void matrixACreate(struct  a *);

void *status;  
struct a  
{
     int Arow; // Matrix A    
     int Acol; // WxX  
     int low; // Range low  
     int high;  
};  

int main(int argc, char * argv[])  
{   
    struct a matrix_mult_info;

    matrix_mult_info.Arow = atoi(argv[1]); // Matrix A
    matrix_mult_info.Acol = atoi(argv[2]); // WxX

    matrix_mult_info.low = atoi(argv[5]); // Range low
    matrix_mult_info.high = atoi(argv[6]);

    pthread_t matrixAthread;

    pthread_t runner;
    int error, retValue;

    //if (Acol != Brow)
    //{
    //   cout << " This matrix cannot be multiplied. FAIL" << endl;
    //   return 0;
    //}  
    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IN THE NEXT LINE:  

    error = pthread_create(&matrixAthread, NULL, matrixACreate, matrix_mult_info );    
    // I don't know what to pass as the last parameter

    retValue = pthread_join(matrixAthread, &status);  
    return 0;  
}

void matrixACreate(struct a *matrix) {  
    struct a *data = (struct a *) malloc(sizeof(struct a));  
    data->Arow = matrix->Arow;  
    data->Acol = matrix->Acol;  
    int range = ((matrix->high - matrix->low) + 1);  
    cout << matrix->Arow << endl;  
    free(data);  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227087/error-with-passing-a-pointer-using-threads with the requested info, rather than opening a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Pass a reference to your data into the thread:

```
pthread_create(&matrixAthread, NULL, matrixACreate, &matrix_mult_info);
```

and then in the thread the reference given as the last parameter to `pthread_create` will be the value of the parameter, which you can cast back into the data type of structure passed in:

```
void *matrixACreate(void *td)
{
    struct a *matrix = td;
}
```